# Get the max element in mongodb collection throws exception

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a trouble with the code below. I try to get max(seq) in 'links' collection. After run the code below, I get "**FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory**" error. How can I overcome that problem? Thank you for your replies.

```
db.collection('links', function(err, collection) {  
        var options = { "limit": 1, "sort": [['seq','desc']]};

        collection.find({}, options , function(err, docs) {            
            console.log("Returned #" + docs.seq + " documents");
        }); 
});
```

*Note:*  Memory usage of node has incredibly increased after running, by the way.

Comment: Do you have an index on `seq`?  If not, that query has to load your whole collection into memory.

Comment: I don't have index on it. I try to store seq value on another collection. It may speed up the execution time, I guess.

Comment: It is also good to note that in-memory sort has a limit with or without JS if about 32 meg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an index on `seq` to your collection so that Mongo doesn't have to load the whole collection into memory to sort it.

Also, use `findOne` instead of `find` as the `docs` parameter in your current code is actually a cursor object, not the doc with the max `seq`.  As in:

```
var options = { "sort": [['seq','desc']] };
collection.findOne({}, options , function(err, doc) {
    console.log("Returned #" + doc.seq + " documents");
});
```

Comment: Thank you, Johnny. I stored "seq" value on another collection and overcome it.